# linker problems after updating pods in xcode 7 swift project

Tags: swift, xcode7, cocoapods, linker-errors

I have a project using the following Podfile:

```
target 'XXX' do
    pod 'Google/Analytics'   
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 4.0.1'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
    pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
    pod 'TOCropViewController'

end
```

this compiles and runs perfectly.

once I do $pod update then I get lots of updates, see below:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.6)
Installing Google 3.0.3 (was 2.0.3)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.8.1 (was 7.8.0)
Using GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
Installing GoogleAppUtilities 1.1.1 (was 1.1.0)
Installing GoogleAuthUtilities 2.0.1 (was 2.0.0)
Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities 1.2.1 (was 1.2.0)
Using GoogleMaps (1.13.2)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities 1.2.1 (was 1.2.0)
Installing GoogleSignIn 4.0.0 (was 3.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities 1.1.1 (was 1.1.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities 1.3.1 (was 1.2.0)
Using HockeySDK (4.0.1)
Using TOCropViewController (1.3.7)
Using TesseractOCRiOS (4.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 16
total pods installed.
```

then I try to build and I get the following error:

```
ld: file not found:       /Users/user/Desktop/Personal/xxx/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so I decided to delete the entry from Other Linker Flags **($(PODS_ROOT)/GoogleUtilities/Libraries/libGTM_NSData+zlib_external.a)** and that problem went away, but now I get the following error:

```
ld: file not found: -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am on xcode 7.

any idea? this is driving me nuts.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project, derived data and build folder?

Comment: yes, and no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem on my own.

what I did was:

1. go to my project folder with finder
2. "show package content" for my project.xcodeproj
3. edit the file .pbxproj
4. delete the Other Link section for both debug and release

then I restarted xcode and all worked like a charm again.

phew!